# Drush not working on Multisite with Shared User Table

Tags: users, drush

I have a Drupal 7 Multisite Environment with sub-directories.

(E.g):

- mainsite.com
- mainsite.com/multisite1
- mainsite.com/multisite2
- mainsite.com/multisite3
- etc.

Each website has its own Database and all are on the same Database Server

I recently configured the multisites to have a Shared User table along with a few shared custom User fields and that aspect works.

However, I am now unable to use Drush within the Multiste directories.

Previously, I would CD into the directory and be able to run Drush commands for that specific multisite like this:

```
cd /var/www/mainsite.com/sites/multisite1
drush cc all
```

Now it tells me that "No Drupal site found".

When I comment out the prefix portion of my settings.php file, Drush works again.

How can I make Drush work for these sites?

Below is what my settings.php file looks like:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => '[Multisite DB]',
  'username' => '[Database Username]',
  'password' => '[Database Password]',
  'host' => '[DB Server IP]',
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
  'prefix' => array(
        'default'   => '[Multisite DB].',
        'users'     => '[Main Site DB].',
        'sessions'  => '[Main Site DB].',
        'role'      => '[Main Site DB].',
        'authmap'   => '[Main Site DB].',
        'users_roles'   => '[Main Site DB].',
        'field_data_field_first_name'   => '[Main Site DB].',
        'field_data_field_last_name'   => '[Main Site DB].',
        'field_data_field_title'   => '[Main Site DB].',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being very simple.

I just had to change one line.

I changed this:

```
        'default'   => '[Multisite DB].',
```

to:

```
        'default'   => '',
```

This is how it looks all together.

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => '[Multisite DB]',
  'username' => '[Database Username]',
  'password' => '[Database Password]',
  'host' => '[DB Server IP]',
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
  'prefix' => array(
        'default'   => '',
        'users'     => '[Main Site DB].',
        'sessions'  => '[Main Site DB].',
        'role'      => '[Main Site DB].',
        'authmap'   => '[Main Site DB].',
        'users_roles'   => '[Main Site DB].',
        'field_data_field_first_name'   => '[Main Site DB].',
        'field_data_field_last_name'   => '[Main Site DB].',
        'field_data_field_title'   => '[Main Site DB].',
  ),
);
```

I know that a lot of people use Bakery or are already on Drupal 8, but I hope this helps anyone still on Drupal 7 looking to share a User table across multiple websites with different databases.

Comment: Shared database tables is not necessarily fully supported by Drush; using other solutions are preferable, as you may run into problems with other commands. Glad you got this working for your setup though.